# Unable docker desktop with Window 10 Pro

Tags: docker, installation, window, docker-desktop

I got problems when installing docker-desktop on windows. My Windows version is [Windows 10 Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zbL7.png) but I got [incompatible version of windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HqjS.png) as an error.

I tried updating Windows but it's still not working

Comment: Welcome aboard, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.